# Understand the implementation of event loops in Python asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, events, concurrency

I'm watching [import asyncio: Learn Python's AsyncIO #2 - The Event Loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7Yn5biBZ58) to try to understand the inner working of event loops. In the video, the instructor tried to explain this on the operating system level. However, I know very few about operating systems and have a very hard time understanding his explanation.

**Questions**

At [9:46](https://youtu.be/E7Yn5biBZ58?t=586), the instructor showed a system calls manual about the `select` method.

1. The instructor said that the `select` method allows us to provide a list of file descriptors. What is a file descriptor?
2. What does the `select` method do? What would happen to the provided file descriptors after calling `select` on them?
3. The manual said that the `select` method is 'synchronous I/O multiplexing'. What is multiplexing? In what way is the `select` method 'synchronous I/O multiplexing'?
4. How does the Python implementation of event loops make use of the `select` method?

At [11:11](https://youtu.be/E7Yn5biBZ58?t=671), the instructor showed a Windows Dev Center manual about 'I/O Completion Ports'.

5. The instructor said that "if there are more events than available threads, some events will wait until one of threads in the pool frees up." So basically it works similarly to `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`?
6. How does the Python implementation of event loops make use of 'I/O Completion Ports'?

At [22:31](https://youtu.be/E7Yn5biBZ58?t=1351), the instructor showed the source code of `_run_once` method in `base_events.py`.

7. The second step of `_run_once` method is polling for I/O. Does it polls for I/O by using the `_select.select` method at line 1854 ([24:41](https://youtu.be/E7Yn5biBZ58?t=1481))?

At [25:30](https://youtu.be/E7Yn5biBZ58?t=1530), the instructor showed the source code of `_process_events` method in `selector_events.py`.

8. What do the `mask`, `selectors`, `reader`, `writer` variables in the code refer to? What do they do?

Finally,

9. What kinds of general computer science knowledge do I need to know in order to understand event loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to explain first few but Stack overflow is not a good place for this. I think you can find a lot of info about most of these topics online by googling or taking an online OS course. Other than that, there's no need to understand "under the hood" of something to use it. It's good in the long run but I think it's bad to focus on these stuff first.

> What is a file descriptor?

Let's say you want to read a file. You ask OS, "hey open /some/place/file.txt for me". OS will tell you, "I opened it with file descriptor 152". Then you read the file like, "OS please read 1000 bytes from file descriptor 152". 152 is the file descriptor, just a number denoting the "thing" you want to read/write (e.g. it can be a file, socket, or something else)

> What does the select method do? What would happen to the provided file descriptors after calling select on them?

Let's say you want to read from a socket. You asks OS to "read 100 bytes from socket 189" but the user from other side of socket has sent nothing yet. What will happen? Your program would wait until some data is sent (or and error/timeout occurs). That may suit you but what about if you want to read from socket 189, 541, 449 whichever had sent some data? To do this you can create 3 threads one for each socket and somehow communicate between them but there's cleaner and higher performance alternative.

`select` is a semi-deprecated syscall that does this. You asks OS "hey, select between 189, 541, 449. Which one has data to read?" Then if there's data in let's say 449, OS will return "there's data on 449" otherwise  (if there's no data in any of them) it will block like a normal read until one of the three has something in it.

> The manual said that the select method is 'synchronous I/O multiplexing'. What is multiplexing? In what way is the select method 'synchronous I/O multiplexing'?

Multiplex means getting one output from multiple inputs. Like a tap water that has a cold and warm water input but gives you 1 output water depending on the state of the handle.

Synchronous is about blocking behavior.

> How does the Python implementation of event loops make use of the select method?

Probably it doesn't use it as there are better syscalls like poll/epoll on Linux. I think you need to ask people that are developing Python itself or dive deep into their code, documentation, mailing list.

> What kinds of general computer science knowledge do I need to know in order to understand event loops?

It's better to explain what you're trying to achieve. Seems you don't know the basics of asyncio or OS but trying to understand how Python asyncio implementation is working. Why? And also why asyncio instead of normal blocking?